# Given a ring find two divisors of zero $a$ and $b$ such that their sum is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

> Given the ring $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ find $a$ and $b$, two divisors of zero, such that their sum is a unit.

Given the ring $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. So by two divisors of zero what I understand is that $a|6$ and $b|6$, and by their sum is equal to unity $a+b = u$, where $\exists \  v \in \ \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z $ such that $ uv = vu = 1$.

Pairs of distinct elements $a|6$ and $b|6$, are $1,3$ ; $3,2$ ; $1,2$. Their sum is $1+4 = 5$; $2+3 = 5$; $1+2 = 3$.

$ 5 \cdot 5 = 24 \equiv 1 \mod (6)$. That is, $5$ is the only unit that satisfies the condition.

Did I miss something? Is the approach correct? Do I even understand the exercise? Please feel free to correct me.

Thank you very much. Kind regards.

Comment: It is not enough for something to "divide $6$" (ie., $0$). After all units divide everything, and they are *never* zero divisors. A zero divisor is an element $a\neq 0$ such that there exists $b\neq 0$ with $ab=0$. Your pairs involving $1$ definitely don't work. Also, you can have something which does not divide $6$ in the integers but is nonetheless a zero divisor: for example, $4$: because $4\times 3 \equiv 0\pmod{6}$.

Comment: Couple of things that need to be fixed. Firstly $0 \in \Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$. Moreover the word "unity" is usually used for $1$. Did you by any chance mean "unit"?

Comment: btw, adding on to @ArturoMagidin, $3+4=1$.

Comment: Assuming you meant $a+b=1$, then you are looking for $a$ such that $a(1-a) \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$.

Comment: Technically, the elements of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ are cosets of the form $a+6\mathbb Z.$ And you forgot $0$ in the set.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. My bad.

Comment: @ArturoMagdin, ah ok thanks that makes sense. So the zero-divisors would be  2, 3, 4?   Would 2+3 = 5 work?

Comment: @AnuragA, yes meant unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments there seems to be some misconception about the term "zero divisor". To make it perfectly clear: given a ring $R$ an element $a\in R$ is called a *zero divisor* if there exists $b\in R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $ab=0$. In particular, $0$ is **always** a zero divisor a rings for which this is the only zero divisor are called *integral domains*.

Back to $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. An element $a$ here is a zero divisor iff there is some non-zero $b$ such that $ab=0$. As $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is quite a small ring you can simply check all elements to find that $0,2,3,4$ are the only zero divisors (you missed $0$ in your comment; see what I wrote above). Also, $1$ is **always** a unit and you showed that $5$ is a unit too. So, there are two immediate possiblities: $(a,b)=(2,3)$ or $(a,b)=(3,4)$. As you are only asked to find *a* pair $(a,b)$ such that $a+b$ is a unit this should suffice.

---

Two facts to prove which might be a good training for better understanding units and zero divisors:

**Fact $\mathbf1$.** Let $R$ be a ring. If $u\in R$ is a unit then $u$ is *not* a zero divisor.
**Fact $\mathbf2$.** Let $R=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Then $R$ decomposes disjointly into its set of units and zero divisors. That means every element of $R$ is either a unit or a zero divisor. (This holds more generally for all finite rings)